# Calculating datetime difference using ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, datetime

How would I calculate the time difference between two fields?

For Example: 3/22/2018 7:08:00 AM - 3/22/2018 7:07:30 AM

Answer (score 2):

Use the datatime library!

```
import datetime
time1 = "3/22/2018 7:08:00 AM"
time2 = "3/22/2018 7:07:30 AM"

date_time_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
date_time_obj2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

print(date_time_obj1 - date_time_obj2)
```

This will return 0:0:30.  You may need to study up on datatimes and their conversions with Python to get the time in a format you want because this will return a Python datetime object.
For more information see these links : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime